# htaccess remove directory from url and keep access parent directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Folder and file structures

```
public_html/
           web/index.php
           upload/img.jpg
```

I need mysite.com/web/index.php to become mysite.com/index.php
This is my htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ web/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ web/$1
```

it works perfectly for me. but i can't access directory "upload/img.jpg" anymore.
can i still access mysite.com/upload/img.jpg ?

Thank you in advance for your time.

Kind regards.

Comment: I don't understand the first RewriteRule, but apart from that: you could simply do an "exception rule" for the upload directory which you place _before_ the rule rewriting requests to /web. Add the `[L]` flag to that rule and the rewriting of requests to /upload will stop if that first exception rule matches.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this rule instead:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule !^(web|upload) web%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
```

This will skip this rule if requested URI is for `/web/` or `/upload/`

Answer (score 0):

Now I can answer my question.

This is .htaccess in folder /public_html/

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ web/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ web/$1
```

and this is .htaccess in folder /public_html/web/

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule    ^uploads/(.*)  /uploads/$1 [PT]
```